# How to trade at Athens Stock Exchange (ASE)

Tags: trading, online-brokerage, online-trading, international-trading, greece

I am completely new to trading and would like to start trading at the ASE with an international online broker preferably. I am really struggling to find a brokerage with a free platform since the ASE isn't the most popular market at the moment. Any suggestions please?

Comment: In which country do you reside?  Do you already have a source of funds in Greece (a bank account, for example)?

Comment: You are completely new to trading and you want to start off trading the Athens SE, well go ahead and throw your money away. You would think you would want to learn about trading first before throwing your money away.

Comment: There are certainly great opportunities at the Athens Stock Exchange these days, but not for newbies. The experts will take all your money, it's safer to spend it in a Casino, and probably more fun.

Comment: Product/service recommendations (which includes brokerages) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Saxo Bank offers direct access to Athens Stock Exchange.

Interactive Brokers is your next best bet, and as you probably already noticed, they do not have a free platform. They are open to US and non-US citizens. Although they do not currently have direct exposure to individual companies on the Athens Stock Exchange, the various european exchanges they do provide direct market access for will give a lot of exposure.

There are a few Greek companies that trade on non-Greek stock exchanges, if you want exposure. There are also Greek ETFs which bundle several companies together or try to replicate Greek company indices.

Comment: Exhibit A: the difference between "the answer" and "advice". This site needs to make up its mind on which it caters to.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea its more of a meta discussion. Often times questions on this site are eligible for answers that are not incorrect, but wouldn't be suitable financial advice for anyone. Such as this speculative stock trading question. Speculative only because it is about Greece In August 2015, because it is August 2015 and about Greece, this question has several votes to close solely because all answers would be advice that nobody wants to be responsible for anybody replicating (and a "product recommendation" as if that never happens legitimately here. Credit Karma is a freaking product)

Comment: IB has many exchanges, but not ASE. See here for all European exchanges offered https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=exchanges&p=europe&ns=T

Comment: @vonMises thanks, that is surprising to me. But there are lots of greek indices cross trading on those exchanges, as well as in the US. I wonder if OP would settle for that.